# Embed PowerBI report server in ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi

I want use report of PowerBI in ASP.NET MVC / Core MVC without authentication in PowerBI or server. I use iframe but when show view
I have to enter username and password

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to embed Power BI in your app.  The [Embed for Your Organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core), which requires the user to log in with their AAD account, and the [Embed for Your Customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) where the users don't authenticate directly to Power BI.  You use whatever authentication scheme you want in your app, and have a single Master User or Service Principal to authenticate to Power BI.

Comment: How can i use single master user ?

Comment: The master user is the PowerBI user who generates all the embed tokens for your actual users.